# Restricted probability measure definition and property

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a probability measure space.

Let $\mathcal{F}'\subset \mathcal{F}$ be a sub-sigma-algebra.

According to [WikiProof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Restricted_Measure), the restricted measure $\mu|_{\mathcal{F}'}$on $\mathcal{F}'$ is defined as

$$
\forall E \in \mathcal{F}', \quad \mu(E) = \mu|_{\mathcal{F}'}(E).
$$

[The proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Restricted_Measure_is_Measure) shows that $\mu|_{\mathcal{F}'}$ is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}')$.

Now I would like to define an extended restricted measure such that $\tilde{\mu}|_{\mathcal{F}'}(A)=0$ for any $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $A\notin \mathcal{F}'$.

Questions are

1. Is $\tilde{\mu}|_{\mathcal{F}'}(A)$ a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$? I found the pairwise disjoint union axiom difficult to prove.
2. If not, how to extend $\tilde{\mu}|_{\mathcal{F}'}(A)$ so that it is a measure on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\Omega$ belongs to every sigma algebra on $\Omega$. It belongs to $\mathcal F'$ in particular and  $\mu|_{\mathcal F'}(\Omega)=\mu (\Omega)=1$. So $\mu|_{\mathcal F'}$ is a probaility measure.

$\mu|_{\mathcal F'}$ is defined only for sets in $\mathcal F'$, so $\mu|_{\mathcal F'}(A)$ does not even make sense when $A \notin \mathcal F'$.
Just defining it as $0$ for sets not in $\mathcal F'$ will not yield a measure.

An obvious extension of the restricted measure to $\mathcal F$ is $\mu$ itself.

For the edited version of 1) the answer is the restriction of $\mu$ is not defined on $\mathcal F$, so the question of its countbale additivity does not arise. Its countable aditivity on $\mathcal F'$ is obvious.

Comment: Is it okay to define an extended restricted measure with property 2 also hold?

Comment: @NathanExplosion No. that will not give you  a measure on $\mathcal F$.

Comment: Sorry sir, I modified my question.

Comment: But if we use $\mu$ as the extension then we cannot have the $\mu(A)=0$ property for $A$ outside of $\mathcal{F}'$.

Comment: @NathanExplosion Yes, $\mu(A)=0$ for A$ \notin \mathcal F'$ is a bad idea  becasue it destroys countable additivity.