# How is a restricted measure defined over sets not in sub-sigma algebra?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, geometric-measure-theory, outer-measure, borel-measures

According to [ProofWiki](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Restricted_Measure) given a measure space $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X}, \mu)$ and a subsigma algebra $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq\mathcal{X}$, the restriction of $\mu$ to $\mathcal{Y}$ is the measure $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}:\mathcal{X}\to[0, +\infty]$ (**important: it's domain is $\mathcal{X}$, not $\mathcal{Y}$!!**)
$$
\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}(\mathrm{A}) = \mu(\mathrm{A}) \qquad \forall \mathrm{A}\in\mathcal{Y}
$$

> **QUESTION:** The domain of $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}$ is $\mathcal{X}$ but the definition only specifies how to measure sets $\mathrm{A}\in\mathcal{Y}$. How is the restriction defined for $\mathrm{B}\in\mathcal{X}$ with $\mathrm{B}\notin \mathcal{Y}$?

According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4067929/restricted-probability-measure-definition-and-property) post it ***does not*** assign measure zero to sets $\mathrm{B}$ above. Then what does it assign to them? It must assign something because it is defined over them.

Comment: @Surb So do you think there is a typo in ProofWiki?

Comment: All my excuse, I thought that $\mathcal Y$ was a set and not a $\sigma -$algebra. So, $\mu|_{\mathcal Y}$ is not defined on $\mathcal X$.

Comment: @Surb Let me get this straight, there's two definitions at play. Given a sub-sigma algebra $\mathcal{Y}\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ the restriction of a measure to the subsigma algebra is $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}$ and this is defined *only* on $A\in\mathcal{Y}$ as $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}(A) = \mu(A)$. 

However, given a set $B\in\mathcal{X}$ the restriction of a measure to a measurable set $\mu\restriction_{B}$ is defined on all $A\in\mathcal{X}$ as $\mu\restriction_{B}(A) = \mu(A\cap B)$?

Comment: yes exactly. Notice that $\mu|_B$ is the same as $\mu_{\mathcal Z}$ for $\mathcal Z$ being the $\sigma -$algebra defined by $\mathcal Z=\{A\cap B\mid A\in \mathcal X\}$.

Comment: @Surb Ah I think I've seen that sub-sigma algebra somewhere before. If I am not wrong, $\mathcal{Z}$ is often indicated by $\mathcal{X}\restriction_{B}$ and called the sigma-algebra restricted to $B$. 

I am still very confused as to why $\mu_{\mathcal{Y}}$ is not defined on $\mathcal{X}$

Comment: Regarding your comment, you're right $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{X}\restriction_{B}}$ is equivalent to $\mu\restriction_{B}$. The first is
$$
\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{X}\restriction_{B}}(E) = \mu(E) \qquad \forall\,E\in\mathcal{X}\restriction_{B}
$$
The second is 
$$
\mu\restriction_{B}(E) = \mu(E\cap B) \qquad E\in\mathcal{X}
$$
The two are equivalent because $E\in\mathcal{X}\restriction_{B}$ means $E\in\mathcal{X}$ and $E\subseteq B$. That is $E = E \cap B$.

Comment: @Surb Also, going back to your point that $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}$ is not defined on the whole of $\mathcal{X}$. Does it mean ProofWiki is wrong and one should write $\mu\restriction_{\mathcal{Y}}:\mathcal{Y}\to[0, +\infty]$?

Comment: yes absolutely.

Comment: This has been corrected, looks like it was a typo that's laid there for a while. Please do let us know when you find stuff like this - though I do search ProofWiki here occassionally

Comment: @GeorgeCoote Thank you and yes I didn't think about it, will let you know next time!